# Disable emacs from converting tabs to spaces

Tags: emacs, indentation, auto-indent, spacemacs

I've recently started using Emacs and an issue I've been facing is that the editor automatically converts all the tabs to spaces. It has started to get a bit annoying now.

Here's my `.emacs` file for reference:

```
(require 'package)
(let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
                    (not (gnutls-available-p))))
       (proto (if no-ssl "http" "https")))
  (when no-ssl
    (warn "\
Your version of Emacs does not support SSL connections,
which is unsafe because it allows man-in-the-middle attacks.
There are two things you can do about this warning:
1. Install an Emacs version that does support SSL and be safe.
2. Remove this warning from your init file so you won't see it again."))
  ;; Comment/uncomment these two lines to enable/disable MELPA and MELPA Stable as desired
  (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa" (concat proto "://melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  ;;(add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa-stable" (concat proto "://stable.melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  (when (< emacs-major-version 24)
    (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "gnu" (concat proto "://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))
(package-initialize)

(custom-set-variables
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (dracula)))
 '(custom-safe-themes)
 '(display-line-numbers-type (quote relative))
 '(global-display-line-numbers-mode t)
 '(menu-bar-mode nil)
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (company-irony-c-headers company-irony micgoline elpy company-jedi molokai-theme gruvbox-theme autopair auto-complete anaconda-mode nyan-mode dracula-theme company)))
 '(scroll-bar-mode nil)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
 )

(setq make-backup-files nil)
(setq auto-save-default nil)
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)   ;; hide the startup message

(elpy-enable)
(pyenv-mode)
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --simple-prompt")
(require 'powerline)
```

Any suggestions on how to stop emacs from doing this behaviour?

Comment: Did you check variable indent-tabs-mode? With this you should be able to switch between emacs using spaces or tabs.

Comment: @AltruisticDelay: Please post that as an answer. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: If you only want *spaces* then `indent-tabs-mode` (disabled) is all you need.  If you want *tabs*, then you may need to understand other things as well, as tabs will only be used per `tab-width` columns, which means you *may* need to configure additional things to ensure that every indent is an exact multiple of `tab-width`.  These things can be specific to the major-mode, but `M-x apropos-variable` searching for `offset` and `indent` can be handy.  `M-x customize-group` for the library in question ought to show you what you need to know, too.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Drew, I am posting this as answer:

Did you check variable `indent-tabs-mode`?

With this you should be able to switch between emacs using spaces or tabs.

As described in the emacs wiki [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentationBasics) I would assume, some active mode is setting this to nil in your emacs. 
You can find another explanation with links to discussions about if tabs are evil or not [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NoTabs)

EDIT:
It seems that strangely the python-mode sets `indent-tabs-mode` to t.
Maybe this Emacs Wiki [entry](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingPython) solves your problem. This snippet from the wiki:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
        (setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
        (setq-default tab-width 4)
        (setq-default py-indent-tabs-mode t)
    (add-to-list 'write-file-functions 'delete-trailing-whitespace)))
```

looks like it will do the trick.
Hope this helps.

Comment: doesn't really work. I added `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)` to my .emacs config file. But it doesn't seem to work either. I still get spaces instead of tabs in my files.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Bhoi: Modified my answer to set correct indent in python mode hook. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: still doesn't work. I'm editing a c++ file in case that makes a difference.

Comment: you know what's the most fascinating part? I completely erased the .emacs file, and still it automatically converts all my tabs to spaces (*sighs*)

Comment: In your python buffer, what are the values for indent-tabs-mode and py-indent-tabs-mode and what happens if you set it explicitly in this buffer?